# Robotics StackExchange vs ROS Answer

Tags: ros, robotc

Robotics Stackexchange vs. ROS Answer:
What is better and for what purpose?

Comment: Robotics.SE is about all robotics and answers.ros is about ROS only. What's not clear about it?

Answer (score 2):

The following are very common in software driven robotics:

- Ros
- ubuntu
- c++
- python
- arduino

You may notice that all of those have a .stackexchange. But robotics may not always involve these.  And it's bigger than all of those.

Neither is better. They have different purposes.

Comment: There are no subdomains for ROS, c++ and python on stackexchange... Ros is part of robotics and c++/python is part of stackoverflow.